# java-test-fixtures unable use with Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, java-test-fixtures

I have set java-test-fixtures for sharing test sources between multi-module project. Everythig looks good, but code of testFixtures module are generated to `build/classes/testFixtures`. But when I start building jar of other modules it returns me error that plugin try to find sources of fixtures in path `\core\build\classes\java\testFixtures` as it does not exist. I can't find options for customize plugin to search in other path or how set gradle build for java folder instead to kotlin

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set in project manually composing of JAR which task have filter for files/folders... after rebuild gradle task to creating JAR file by shadow plugin...testFixtures are available in JAR for tests